# CKEditor5 Text Alignment Plugin - Possible to force "text-align: left:" to be inserted, instead of being removed?

Tags: text, alignment, ckeditor5

Working on an inline text editing tool for our clients' text content and we allow them to adjust text alignment using CKEditor5's text alignment plugin.  Clients' text content is within a section and a section can have a default text alignment (left, center, or right).  Say, for the case when the section default alignment is centered, if a client tries to adjust some or all of the text content to be left aligned using CKEditor, the text will remain centered due to the alignment plugin not inserting "text-align: left".  Is there any way to configure the plugin to force the insertion of "text-align: left", instead of removing it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, one of my coworkers was able to make it work by modifying the isDefault() function that's found in the plugin code.  By making the function always return false, it allowed "text-align: left" to be inserted when align left is applied.